# How to initialize var?

Tags: c#, initialization

Can I initialize var with null or some empty value?

Comment: Do you mean the C# keyword `var` or do you mean variables in general?

Comment: I want the variable to perform a linq query after initiization

Comment: why not initialize it when you use it?

Comment: No the var initialization is above if statement which will execute the query based on the condition and will use the same variable

Comment: assign (dynamic) null;
refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111917/linq-initialize-var-to-null

Comment: var abc = (dynamic)null;
This is how you can do in C#

Answer (score 75, accepted):

C# is a **strictly/strongly typed language**. var was introduced for compile-time type-binding for [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) yet you can use var for primitive and custom types that are already known at design time. At runtime there's nothing like var, it is replaced by an actual type that is either a reference type or value type.

When you say,

```
var x = null;
```

the compiler cannot resolve this because there's no type bound to null. You can make it like this.

```
string y = null;
var x = y;
```

This will work because now x can know its type at compile time that is string in this case.

Answer (score 54):

Well, as others have stated, ambiguity in type is the issue. So the answer is no, C# doesn't let that happen because it's a strongly typed language, and it deals only with compile time known types. The compiler could have been designed to infer it as of type `object`, but the designers chose to avoid the extra complexity (in C# `null` has no type).

One alternative is

```
var foo = new { }; //anonymous type
```

Again note that you're initializing to a compile time known type, and at the end its not `null`, but anonymous object. It's only a few lines shorter than `new object()`. **You can only reassign the anonymous type to `foo` in this one case, which may or may not be desirable**.

Initializing to `null` with type not being known is out of question.

Unless you're using `dynamic`.

```
dynamic foo = null;
//or
var foo = (dynamic)null; //overkill
```

Of course it is pretty useless, unless you want to reassign values to `foo` variable. You lose intellisense support as well in Visual Studio.

Lastly, as others have answered, you can have a specific type declared by casting;

```
var foo = (T)null;
```

So your options are:

```
//initializes to non-null; I like it; cant be reassigned a value of any type
var foo = new { }; 

//initializes to non-null; can be reassigned a value of any type
var foo = new object();

//initializes to null; dangerous and finds least use; can be reassigned a value of any type
dynamic foo = null;
var foo = (dynamic)null;

//initializes to null; more conventional; can be reassigned a value of any type
object foo = null;

//initializes to null; cannot be reassigned a value of any type
var foo = (T)null;
```

Comment: Good list of options. +1

Comment: Why is `dynamic foo = null;` dangerous?

Comment: @christian, I don't remember what I had in mind then, but in vast majority of the cases `object foo = null` will do. If you are really trying to intialize a dynamic variable, then fine, just would lose compile time safety.

Answer (score 49):

This is the way how to **intialize value** to **var variable**

```
var _myVal = (dynamic)null;
```

Answer (score 35):

Why wouldn't this be possible?

```
var theNameOfTheVar = (TheType)null;
```

eg:

```
var name = (string)null;
```

Simple as that.

Comment: This is certainly a working solution, but I really can't come up with any reason to use it.

Comment: There is none. I'm just answering the TS' question :)

Comment: it's very useful not directly for the var but for properties of an anonymous type like var anonType = new{ Example = (TheType) null};

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk In my case, this helped me in unit tests - if you expect null: var expected = (string)null;

Comment: This is the correct answer, works flawlessly on older versions such as 7. No errors while compiling assigning it later.

Comment: I get a CS8600 warning "Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type." when I do this with nullable reference types enabled. The warning disappears if you cast null to nullable type, i.e. `var name = (string?)null;`.

Answer (score 9):

A `var` cannot be set to `null` since it needs to be statically typed.

```
var foo = null;
// compiler goes: "Huh, what's that type of foo?"
```

However, you can use this construct to work around the issue:

```
var foo = (string)null;
// compiler goes: "Ah, it's a string. Nice."
```

I don't know for sure, but from what I heard you can also use `dynamic` instead of `var`. This does not require static typing.

```
dynamic foo = null;
foo = "hi";
```

Also, since it was not clear to me from the question if you meant the `var`keyword or variables in general: Only references (to classes) and nullable types can be set to null. For instance, you can do this:

```
string s = null; // reference
SomeClass c = null; // reference
int? i = null; // nullable
```

But you cannot do this:

```
int i = null; // integers cannot contain null
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation SomeClass c = null; works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. `var` needs to be initialized to a type, it can't be null.

Comment: Ding!  Var is kind of like saying to the compiler "I don't feel like declaring this but you'll know" ... saying var whatever = null is like doing a headfake.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think you can assign it to a new object. Something like:

```
var v = new object();
```

Answer (score 4):

`var` just tells the compiler to infer the type you wanted at compile time...it cannot infer from `null` (though there are cases it *could*).

So, no you are not allowed to do this.

When you say "some empty value"...if you mean:

```
var s = string.Empty;
//
var s = "";
```

Then yes, you may do that, but not `null`.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot assign null to a var type.

If you assign null the compiler cannot find the variable you wanted in var place.

throws error: `Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable`

you can try this:

```
var dummy =(string)null;
```

Here compiler can find the type you want so no problem

You can assign some empty values.

```
var dummy = string.Empty;
```

or

```
var dummy = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't initialise var with null, var needs to be initialised as a type otherwise it cannot be inferred, if you think you need to do this maybe you can post the code it is probable that there is another way to do what you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr.Snake, Found this helpfull for another trick i was looking for :) (Not enough rep to comment)

Shorthand assignment of nullable types.
Like this:

```
var someDate = !Convert.IsDBNull(dataRow["SomeDate"])
                    ? Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow["SomeDate"])
                    : (DateTime?) null;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `default` keyword?

```
var foo = default(SomeClass);
```

Compiler doesn't lose what type the `foo` has. `foo` will have default value of reference type, `null`

Comment: Although this would be an answer to his question, I think it would not be desirable to allow such practices to be in your code. this would be the same as saying ``SomeClass foo = null;``

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Diceble I totally agree with you. I would just avoid this kind of case during coding myself.