# Initialize value of 'var' in C# to null

Tags: c#, var

I want to assign a variable to an initial value of null, and assign its value in the next `if`-`else` block, but the compiler is giving an error,

> Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904689/how-to-initialize-var

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`var` variables still have a type - and the compiler error message says this type *must be established during the declaration*.

The specific request (assigning an initial null value) can be done, but I don't recommend it. It doesn't provide an advantage here (as the type must still be specified) and it could be viewed as making the code less readable:

```
var x = (String)null;
```

Which is still "type inferred" and equivalent to:

```
String x = null;
```

The compiler *will not* accept `var x = null` because it doesn't associate the null with any type - not even Object. Using the above approach, `var x = (Object)null` would "work" although it is of questionable usefulness.

Generally, when I can't use `var`'s type inference correctly then

1. I am at a place where it's best to declare the variable explicitly; or
2. I should rewrite the code such that a *valid* value (with an established type) is assigned during the declaration.

The second approach can be done by moving code into methods or functions.

Comment: It's the same with lambda arrows and method groups which also don't have a type by themselves. For example `var isEven = i => i % 2 == 0;` won't compile. We must exchange `var` with something like `Func<int, int>`, `Predicate<int>`, `MyDelegate`, `Expression<Func<int, int>>`, etc. Or, if we insist on using `var`, we could do like above, `var isEven = (Func<int, int>)(i => i % 2 == 0;)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's partly a "limitation" of the specification at this point (at least up to C#4) :-/ While in the first isEven example the types are not immediately resolvable without external context (because i is unbound), I really wish that something like `var x = (int y) => y * 2;` was allowed. Note that in this counter-example case a compiler could (and Scala does) infer that `Func<int,int> x = (int y) => y * 2;` as `int y` is given and `int * int -> int`.

Comment: They could do that, yes, but it involves treating `Func` and `Action` types as "finer" than other delegates, and "finer" than `Expression<>` tree types. It would mean that these type became "pre-defined" types in the C# spec. And what to do if a parameter had a modifier like `ref` or `params`? For example `var x = (ref int y) => y = 42;`. They would need to introduce new delegate types with different combinations of `ref`, `out`, `params`, or just not support those cases.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Well, ref and out are rare (for me) and I don't want params in a Func<..> so, give me sugar for my use-cases already! I can see where it would unclear if it should be a Func or Expression though .. C#6? (One thing I *love* about C# is that it's a moving specification; because C#1 was about "on par" with Java.)

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword in C#'s main benefit is to enhance readability, not functionality.  Technically, the `var` keywords allows for some other unlocks (e.g. use of anonymous objects), but that seems to be outside the scope of this question. Every variable declared with the `var` keyword has a type.  For instance, you'll find that the following code outputs "String".

```
var myString = "";
Console.Write(myString.GetType().Name);
```

Furthermore, the code above is equivalent to:

```
String myString = "";
Console.Write(myString.GetType().Name);
```

The `var` keyword is simply C#'s way of saying "I can figure out the type for `myString` from the context, so don't worry about specifying the type."

`var myVariable = (MyType)null` or `MyType myVariable = null` should work because you are giving the C# compiler context to figure out what type `myVariable` should will be.

For more information:

- [How to initialize var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904689/how-to-initialize-var)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: if i have to assign this var to multiple class objects depending upon conditions in if-else blocks , will this work, because we are assigning it to some 'MyType' type, Is it possible to change its type later in code.

Comment: It is only possible to cast it between types.  So you can do something like the following:  `MyType myVariable` and `(MyOtherType)myVariable`.  However, you may want to rethink your pattern if you find you're casting a lot.  Consider options with inheritance or generics.