# if - else initialize var

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, .net-4.0

I have a method which sorts a list < T >  which gets a bool parameter which indicates if to sort by `ascending` or by `descending`.

I would like to use `var` as returned type.

```
protected void SortlistBy(bool IsByDescending)
    {
        var result;  
        // Initialize the var according to parameter value  
        if (IsByDescending == false)
            result  =  listModelElements.OrderBy(x => sort(x)).ToList();
        else
            result  =  listModelElements.OrderByDescending(x => sort(x)).ToList();
    }
```

I get the following error:  `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized`.

Trial to initialize to null of String causes this error: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy'`.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
The method enables derived classes to sort a private list in base-class according to sent properties.

```
 protected void SortlistMBy(Func<MyBaseClass, IComparable> sort, params Func<MyBaseClass, IComparable>[] details )
    {
        var result  =  listOfBase .OrderByDescending(x => sort(x));  

 //HERE WOULD LIKE TO SORT BY DESCENDING  

        foreach(var detail in details)
        {
            result = result.ThenBy(x => detail(x));
        }

        listOfBase = result.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Try pasting the error in your favorite web search engine or this site's search box: [How to initialize var?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904689/how-to-initialize-var).

Comment: lol, just define the type you are using List<T> result, or move a loosely typed language like python!

Comment: @Nix I have to use var for further usage.

Comment: @CodeCaster initializing to null of string causes `'string' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy'` error.

Comment: Depending on your further usage you need to declare `result` as something like `List<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, not as `string`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, trying `var result = (List)null;` I get `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments`.

Comment: @user3165438 Whatever you need, `var` is not a variable type, it only allows the compiler to infer the type to use given the data you assign to it. Therefore, you can't initialize it to null. As you only return lists, declare result as a `List<T>` ans return it. You can then use a `var x = SortByList(true);` in the calling method, if you want. But the type of `x` will still be `List<T>`.

Comment: @user3165438 You could do that : `var result = (List<T>)null;` is your method was generic (i.e. `SortlistBy<T>` or seomthing). But that's exactly the same as `List<T> result = null;`

Comment: @X.L.Ant I get `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @user3165438 I guess that's because your method is not generic (it works with a generic one). What I mean is that you don't have any advantage using `var` here, as you know what type your variable will use.

Comment: @user3165438 That's not the same question. What's the problem here ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant That's it! I would like to send a first parameter which indicates if to order by asc or desc. Then I replaced the beginning of method with code from beginning of question.

Comment: @user3165438 I still don't see why you couldn't use a `List<MyBaseClass>` instead of var for initialization.