# Why is that var can only be declared and initialized in a single statement?

Tags: c#

Why is that var can only be declared and initialized in a single statement in C#?

I mean why we cannot use:

```
var x;

x = 100;
```

Since it is a implicit typed local variable "var" and the compiler takes the type that is right of the variable assignment operator, why would it matter that it should be only declared and initialized in a single statement?

Comment: because it identifies type at compile time itself...you might want to use Dynamic

Comment: Each statement *by itself* should be legal without depending on other statements. The compiler cannot make sense of `var x;`.

Comment: If you want to do that use `dynamic`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904689/how-to-initialize-var

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the statement which declares the variable needs to imply the type in order for the compiler to know what to do with `var`.  Sure, you as a person with your own intuition can logically step through the code and determine what the type *will* be.  But the compiler isn't as complex as human intuition.  It needs the type defined *in that statement* in order to compile that statement as a logically complete action.

Every statement needs to individually be complete and compilable.

Comment: But theoretically there is nothing preventing a more complex implementation of an inferring mechanism. Counter examples as given in other answers don't contradict this as the compiler could output an ambiguity error in those cases. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman: Theoretically, yes. But there are a lot of things to consider when defining the standards for a language. Whether or not as a theoretical proof of concept the feature can be implemented is one thing, but actually implementing it, unambiguously, for all possible cases, with full test coverage, backwardly-compatible in all future versions, with a well-defined standard to be unambiguously implemented by other compilers and syntax checkers and various other systems... It gets complex fast. As Eric Lippert once answered, the question isn't "can we?", but "is there really a need to?"

Answer (score 3):

First, because the compiler is only this smart.

Second, because it will actually lower the readability - you won't be able to quickly deduce the type of the variable by looking at its definition.

Answer (score 2):

That's not allowed because you would be able to do this:

```
var a;
if (someCondition)
   a = 3;
else
   a = "abc";
```

C# has to know variable types at compile time and in this case it would known the type only at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are asking why the compiler can't determine the type at the first assignment, rather than at the declaration, right? Consider the following:

```
var x;

if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 12)
{
    x = 100;
}
else
{
    x = "Hello";
}
```

What is the compiler to do? The if-statement can only be evaluated at runtime, not at compile-time when the type has to be identified. But at compile-time, it could still either be an int or a string.

Answer (score 1):

var is really just syntactic sugar. It's shorthand so you don't have to write out the variable type but under the hoods C# is still a strongly typed language.

The compiler determines the type from the assignment. Since you're assigning on a following line, it can't determine the type.