# What is the best practice of declaring a variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904689/how-to-initialize-var) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113262/why-declare-variables-close-to-where-they-are-used) but it is not really related to my question.

let's say we have two examples:

- Example 1:

  ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string  My_Variable;

          .

          // do stuff with My_Variable ...


       }
  }
  ```

Example 2:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    string  My_Variable;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

            .

            // do stuff with My_Variable ...


      }
}
```

In example 1, is firing the `button1` event multiple times mean that the `My_Variable` is declared and assigned memory multiple times?
Which example is the best practice to declare a variable and why?

Thank you

Comment: Research 'scoping' and you will find your answers.

Comment: The first piece of code declares a variable, the second does not -- it declares a field. These concepts are crucially different and whether you use one or the other has nothing to do with "best practice".

Comment: The life time of the variable declared under the button click with only be for the duration of the click event.

Comment: If the variable is needed in more than one method use 2nd example, otherwise, use 1st example.

Answer (score 2):

My_Variable in your two examples performs different functions..

In the first its in scope purely for the duration of the click - meaning if you never click, its never made, and if you click once, its made and forgotten.

In your second, its part of the form class, and is available throughout any of the methods in your form..

You are comparing apples and pears.

Answer (score 0):

The first declarationvariable has its scope throughout the click event only where as the second declaration  variable has its scope throughout the class.

It has nothing to do with the best practice. It depends on your requirement completely.