# C# assign val1 or val2

Tags: c#

is there a way in C# to assign a default value in var if the value we want is null ?

ex:
var = something or "default value"

I'm looking for a simpler way than var = something != null ? something : "default value"

Comment: Try to read documentation before asking here.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904689/7517846)

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this;

```
   var x = y ?? "Default Value"
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I don't know why but I thought it only works on boolean. My bad